# If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is bounded then $L(f,[a, b])=\lim _{n\to\infty} L(f, P_n,[a, b])$ and $U(f,[a, b])=\lim _{n\to\infty} U(f, P_n,[a, b])$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, partitions-for-integration

I am trying to prove the following statement from Axler's MIRA book:

"Suppose $f:[a, b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is a bounded function. For $n \in \mathbf{Z}^{+}$, let $P_n$ denote the partition that divides $[a, b]$ into $2^n$ intervals of equal size. Prove that
$L(f,[a, b])=\lim _{n\to\infty} L(f, P_{n},[a, b])$ and $U(f,[a, b])=\lim _{n\to\infty} U(f, P_n,[a, b])$."

I have proved that $\lim_{\to\infty} (,_,[,])\leq (,[,])$ (Since $(,[,])=\sup_ (,,[,])$ it follows that $(,_.[,])\leq (,[,])$ for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and result follows) but I have found it difficult to prove the other inequality, namely that $\lim_{\to\infty} (,_,[,])\leq (,[,])$.

---

EDIT: Proof that $\lim_{\to\infty} (,_,[,])\leq (,[,])$.

Since $L(f,[a,b])=\sup_P (f,P,[a,b])$ there exists a partition $P_{\varepsilon}=\{x_{0_{\varepsilon}},x_{1_{\varepsilon}},x_{2_{\varepsilon}},\dots,x_{N_{\varepsilon}}\}$ such that $L(f,[a,b])-\varepsilon\leq L(f,P_{\varepsilon},[a,b])$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$, $M:=\sup_{[a,b]}f+1$,
$L:=\inf_{P_\varepsilon}|x_{j_{\varepsilon}}-x_{j_{\varepsilon-1}}|$ and $P_N$ be the partition of $[a,b]$ into $2^n$ subintervals of length $\frac{b-a}{2^N}<\min\{L,\frac{\varepsilon}{2MN_{\varepsilon}}\}$.

Then we can see $L(f,P_N,[a,b])$ as composed of two pieces: one where no subinterval of $P_N$ contains any point of $P_{\varepsilon}$ and where the summands of $L(f,P_N,[a,b])$ are bigger than those of $L(f,P_{\varepsilon},[a,b])$ (since $\inf(A)\geq\inf(B)$ if $A\subset B$), and another, where the subintervals of $P_N$ contain points of $P_{\varepsilon}$, and which can subtract at most $N_{\varepsilon}\sup_{[a,b]}f\frac{\varepsilon}{2MN_{\varepsilon}}<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Now, since $L(f,P_N,[a,b])\geq L(f,P_{\varepsilon},[a,b])-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$, we have that $L(f,P_N,[a,b])\geq L(f,P_{\varepsilon},[a,b])$, as desired.

Is the above reasoning correct? Can it be improved? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing $\lim_{n \to \infty} L(f,P_n,[a,b]) = L(f,[a,b])$, where $P_n$ is partition of $[a,b]$ into $2^n$ subintervals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3018453/showing-lim-n-to-infty-lf-p-n-a-b-lf-a-b-where-p-n-is-partit)

Comment: @Arctic Char thank you for your interest in my question; I already know about that question, I have read it but I have found the answers given to be either incomplete or quite confusing (that is true also for the other question I have found about this same problem) that is why I decided to ask this to settle the matter once and for all.

Comment: Then you will need to tell us what is wrong in their answer. In particular [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3018679/629362), which exactly deal with your problem here.

Comment: @ArcticChar In a couple of hours I will modify my question (I can't right now).

Comment: To say " where the summands of $L(f,P_N,[a,b])$ are bigger than those of $L(f,P_{\varepsilon},[a,b])$ (since $\inf(A)\geq\inf(B)$ if $A\subset B$)" does not make sense as the two partitions have potentially overlapping subintervals.  There are other problems as well in trying to directly compare lower sums for $P_N$ and $P_\epsilon$.  You need to introduce a common refining partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lower Darboux integral $L(f)$ is the supremum of lower Darboux sums formed with every partition. Hence, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a partition$P_\epsilon$ such that

$$L(f) - \frac{\epsilon}{2} < L(f,P_\epsilon) \leqslant L(f)$$

Let $N_\epsilon$ denote the number of subintervals in the partition $P_\epsilon$. With $M = \sup_{x \in [a,b]}|f(x)|$ it follows that the oscillation of $f$ over any subinterval $I$ satisfies $$\sup_{x \in I}f(x) - \inf_{x \in I} f(x) \leqslant 2M$$

Let $P_n$ be a dyadic partition where the length of each of the $2^N$ subintervals is bounded as

$$\|P_N\|= \frac{b-a}{2^N}\leqslant \frac{\epsilon}{4MN_\epsilon}$$

If we can show that

$$L(f) - \epsilon < L(f,P_N) \leqslant L(f)$$

then we have proved that $\lim_{n \to \infty}L(f,P_n) = L(f)$ since the lower sums $L(f,P_n)$ form an increasing sequence and, consequently, $L(f) - \epsilon < L(f,P_n) \leqslant L(f)$ for all $n \geqslant N$.  Note that the inequality $L(f,P_N) \leqslant L(f)$ on the RHS is always satisfied regardless of how $P_N$ is chosen since the lower integral is an upper bound for all lower sums.

The correct approach is to introduce the common refinement $Q = P_N \cup P_\epsilon$.  Since $Q \supset P_\epsilon$ we immediately have $L(f,P_\epsilon) \leqslant L(f,Q)$ and, thus,

$$\tag{*}L(f) - \frac{\epsilon}{2} < L(f,Q) \leqslant L(f)$$

It is now easy to compare the magnitude of lower sums $L(f,P_N)$ and $L(f,Q)$ because every subinterval of $P_N$ is a union of subintervals of $Q$.  (This is not the case in your approach where you tried to compare -- incorrectly -- $L(f,P_N)$ and $L(f,P_\epsilon)$ since the subintervals may overlap.)

The partition $Q$ contains at most $N_\epsilon - 1$ more subintervals than $P_N$.  If a subinterval $I$ of $P_N$ contains $q$ points from $P_\epsilon$ in its interior, then $I = \cup_{j=1}^qI_j$ where the $I_j$ are subintervals of $Q$.  We then have

$$\inf_{x \in I}f(x)l(I) \leqslant \sum_{j=1}^q\inf_{x \in I_j}f(x)l(I_j),$$

where $l(I)$ denotes the length of the subinterval. Since $l(I) = \sum_{j=1}^q l(I_j)$, we can bound the difference in contributions to lower sums as

$$\left|\inf_{x \in I}f(x)l(I)-  \sum_{j=1}^q\inf_{x \in I_j}f(x)l(I_j)\right| = \left|\sum_{j=1}^q(\inf_{x \in I}f(x)-  \inf_{x \in I_j}f(x))l(I_j)\right|\\ \leqslant q\cdot 2M \cdot \|P_N\| $$

Summing over all subintervals of $P_N$, we get

$$|L(f,P_N) - L(f,Q)| \leqslant (N_\epsilon-1)\cdot 2M \cdot \|P_N\| \leqslant (N_\epsilon-1)\cdot 2M \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{4MN_\epsilon}\leqslant \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Thus,

$$L(f,P_N) \geqslant L(f,Q) - \frac{\epsilon}{2},$$

and from (*) we get

$$L(f) \geqslant L(f,P_N) \geqslant L(f,Q) - \frac{\epsilon}{2} \geqslant L(f) - \frac{\epsilon}{2} - \frac{\epsilon}{2} = L(f) - \epsilon,$$

completing the proof.

Comment: thank you very much for your great answer, this I just what I was looking for; now I see why it was so difficult to compare the two partitions, I should have looked at the common refinement of the two. Just one more question: why $q\cdot 2M\cdot ||P_n||$ and not $q\cdot2M\cdot ||P_n||$? Where does the $2$ come from?

Comment: @lorenzo: You're welcome.  As to your question, note that $\left|\sum_{j=1}^q(\inf_{X \in I}f(x)-  \inf_{X \in I_j}f(x))l(I_j)\right| \leqslant \sum_{j=1}^q\left|\inf_{X \in I}f(x)-  \inf_{X \in I_j}f(x))\right|l(I_j)$ and $\left|\inf_{X \in I}f(x)-  \inf_{X \in I_j}f(x))\right| \leqslant |\inf_{X \in I}f(x)| + |\inf_{X \in I_j}f(x))|$. Since $|f(x)| \leqslant M$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ we have $-M \leqslant f(x) \leqslant M$ and $-M \leqslant \inf_{x\in I}f(x) \leqslant M$ along with $-M \leqslant \inf_{x\in I_j}f(x) \leqslant M$ .

Comment: Thus,  $|\inf_{x\in I}f(x)| + |\inf_{x\in I_j}f(x)| \leqslant M+M = 2M$.